# Attribute routing to two similar actions on the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller with the two following actions:

```
[Route("api/organization/{orgId}/person/{ver}/getmanagers", Name = "GetManagers")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetManagers(Guid orgId, int ver)
{ .... }

[Route("api/organization/{orgId}/person/{ver}/getpersons", Name = "GetPersons")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPersons(Guid orgId, int ver)
{ .... }
```

When i make a get request to the following url:

```
...api/organization/2473ce5e-42e6-449f-9528-a29000921ded/person/1/getpersons
```

I get this error:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request.
```

Both GetManagers and GetPersons match. Why is this? Why does the "/getpersons" at the end of my url not matter? What can i do to make them separately identifiable?

Answer (score 0):

In Web API the request are mapped to the actions based on HTTP verbs.Change the Default route in WebApiConfig.cs and ensure that you have

```
//Required for Attribute based routing
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

hope this helps.